# android dynamic generate edittext and use its values

Tags: android-view, android, dynamic-ui

My app. has a button which if it's presses a 2 editText fields apear , and if it's pressed again 2 other editText fields apear and so on.
I want to save all the data in this fields in arrayList (or any structure) 
This is a sample of my code 1- The EditText field that apears:

```
<EditText  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
```

> And This is the mainAcvtivity code :

```
LinearLayout lLayout;
ArrayList<String> mArray = new ArrayList<String>();
int numberOfBoxes = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    final EditText AddEduDate = (EditText)inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
    final EditText AddEduInfo = (EditText)inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);

    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lLayout.getChildAt(numberOfBoxes) == null) {

                lLayout.addView(AddEduDate);
                lLayout.addView(AddEduInfo);

                numberOfBoxes += 2; 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Alex .. I want to save all the data in this fields in arrayList (or any structure) , how can i do this ?

Comment: Which kind of data? Text from edit text?

Comment: @articles ... yes the text that the user enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly, simple

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(AddEduDate.getText().toString());
```

should work.

Comment: myproblem is that is dynamic ui .. so if i used your solution the text i got is null

Comment: You should use this in some action, which is triggered by user. When do you want access this fields?

Comment: i want to access this fields when another button is pressed ... but this fields are local variables in onClick method

Comment: so i can't access them in another onClick method of another button

Comment: They are not local

  Button b2 = new Button(this);
  Button b1 = new Button(this);

  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
 
     notificationButtons.addView(AddEduDate);
     notificationButtons.addView(AddEduInfo);

    }
  });

  b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    AddEduDate.getText().toString();

   }
  });
will work, I compiled it at the moment.